# Is there an elegant way to handle potential array element comparison to object value?

Tags: javascript

I have a game in which contestants are presented two pictures at random.  The pictures may be red or blue and the goal is to select any red pictures and submit their vote.  When their vote is cast, they should be awarded a point for any red pictures they selected and a point for any blue pictures they did not select.

Each image has an attribute for the filename and the color, like so:

`<div id="box1" class="selectItem" data-filename="image1.png" data-color="red">`

When a contestant selects one or more images, the filename and color are pushed into an array kept in a hidden form that may look like so:

`[image1.png, red]` but could also look like so: `[image1.png, red, image2.png, blue]` or could also be empty.

I have an object that holds information about the images currently being displayed.  It's built like so:

```
const image1 = $('box1').attr('data-filename');
const color1 = $('box1').attr('data-color');
const image2 = $('box2').attr('data-filename');
const color2 = $('box2').attr('data-color');
const obj = {};
obj[image1] = color1;
obj[image2] = color2;
```

So, the object could look like so:

```
{
  ['image1.png']: 'red',
  ['image2.png']: 'blue'
}
```

All awarded points are then and added to a score kept in sessionStorage.

What's the most elegant way to compare the user's selection (array) against the displayed images (object) to:

1. Award a point for any red images selected
2. Award a point for any blue images NOT selected

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: May I suggest you illustrate your example with something syntactically correct.  Either as JSON:  `{ "image1.png": "red" }`, or as a JavaScript object literal with a dynamic key: `{ ['image1.png']: 'red' }` so that we know you're not trying to do `{ [image1.png]: 'red' }` (access a `png` property of an `image1` variable).

Comment: Please consider an object array: `const arr = [{ "image": "red.png", "chosen":false}, 
{"image": "blue.png", "chosen":false}]` etc

Comment: Then you can use filter on `image==="red.png" && chosen`

Comment: @mplungjan You mean create an object array of all images displayed, then update the "chosen" state based on the presence of the image in the array of selected images, then calculate votes based on the object array values?

Comment: Possibly yes. Depends on what you have first, chicken or the egg? I would have all images in an array and render FROM that array and delegate clicks from the nearest container to store the chosen image state. Then you can at will filter the array on color and chosen state. But it would be such a help if you created a [mcve] as I asked

Comment: If you only have two images, what is the point of the array in the first place. I assume you have many more than two

Comment: @mplungjan There is a large pool of images and two are randomly chosen to be displayed.  The selected images do not have to be an array - they could be an object, as well.  I'll try to create a minimal reproducible example using an object instead of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wound up doing this:

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) { 
    if (key === array[0]) {
        if (value === 'red') {
            // update my score
        }
    } else if (key !== array[0]) {
        if (value === 'blue') {
            // update my score
        }
    }
}
```